# Php variable not saving its value boolean

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling here with a php statement. I can't seem to store a `true` variable which I want to reference later on in php.

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
 <?php $isFound=true;?> 
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php $isFound=false;?> 
<p><?php 
echo $isFound;

_e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? When I try to echo it, it's not showing a value even though the `sorry no posts matched` is displayed fine?

Comment: `echo false;`, basically. `echo` requires a string. `false` is converted to the string `""`, that is, nothing. Try `var_export($isFound);`

Comment: It's better to separate PHP logic from HTML output code. This way you'll prevent unreadable buggy code like so.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol but im wanting to reference that variable latter on and it seems my code cant reference it ? how do i make it proper bollean

Comment: use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` instead of `echo` for debug purposes.

Comment: @david At first I thought it was just a typo, but since you mentioned it again: It's `boolean`, not `bollean`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer it is just a typo sorry i need to set true or false so i can do an if statment later on so how do i check properly if its false

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using echo to check if a value is `true` or `false` since these are booleans and booleans cannot be echoed.

If you really want to use echo though, you can do the following:

```
if ($value === true) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

Otherwise, I would like to suggest using either `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

```
var_dump($isFound);

print_r($isFound);
```

Tip: `var_dump()` and `print_r()` work great with the `<pre />` tag.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($isFound);
echo "</pre>";
```

The above will give you a clearer dump (beautified).

Comment: `xdebug` when enabled will also beautify the output of `var_dump` and allow you to debug your application at runtime to verify the `variable data` using breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't print or echo false statement. If you want to see the value you should use

```
var_dump($isFound);
```